# Why does "auto" not work in this case?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I'm coming back to c++ from a long absence, and am picking up c++11 and boost::asio at the same time.

After GotW [#93](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/13/gotw-93-solution-auto-variables-part-2/) and [#94](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/), I'm naturally fired up about using `auto`.

Imagine my disapointment when this doesn't compile:

```
auto io = boost::asio::io_service{};
```

but I must use this instead:

```
boost::asio::io_service io{};
```

Why does the second compile, but the first not? The error I'm getting is

```
Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'boost::asio::io_service'
```

boost::asio::deadline::timer exhibits the same behavior, but boost::posix_time::seconds does not.

(I'm using xcode + clang + boost 1_55_0).

Full compiling example, modified from the boost asio tutorial:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    using error_code = const boost::system::error_code;

    asio::io_service io{};
    asio::deadline_timer t{io, boost::posix_time::seconds{2}};

    int count = 0;
    std::function<void (const error_code&)> fn = [&](const error_code& e) {
        if (count < 5) {
            std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
            ++(count);
            t.expires_at(t.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds{1});
            t.async_wait(fn);
        }
    };
    t.async_wait(fn);

    io.run();

    std::cout << "Final count is " << count << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please update the code with the missing include files? People will be a lot more willing to help if they can copy-paste your code as is and get it to compile. Nobody wants to play "guess what headers I need to include".

Comment: I think this AAA idea goes a bit too far sometimes. I don't really see the benefit of `auto t = T();` where `T` is a type, not a function. You already know `T`, and it has the extra requirements on `T` that you have discovered here.

Comment: The problem here is that this part of `boost` is old code, and so does not supply appropriate move constructors.

Comment: `auto io = boost::asio::io_service{};` looks pretty odd. Why do a redundant initialization and first hide the type but then don't hide it? `boost::asio::io_service io{};` fixes it, and doesn't have the mentioned drawbacks (no redundancy and no inconsistency).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory, it has nothing to do with the use of `auto`. The following code will produce a similar error message:

```
struct foo
{
    foo() = default;
    foo(foo const&) = delete;
};

foo f = foo{};
```

The last line above requires an accessible copy-constructor (even if the compiler elides the copy).

`boost::asio::io_service`'s copy-constructor is implicitly deleted, probably due to the presence of one or more non-copyable data members or base classes. You already have the right solution to fix the error:

```
asio::io_service io{};
```

Comment: So the problem is my misreading gotw #94 which says "classic" `widget w{ 12, 34 };` should be replaced by "modern" `auto w = widget{ 12, 34 };` and assuming it was only calling the constructor and not *additionally* the copy-constructor. (?)

Comment: Ah! gotw #94 part 6 mentions the type needs to be *movable*.

Comment: @Michael Yes, of course, moveable works too. Also, I'd follow juanchopanza's advice above. I don't see the benefit of using `auto t = T{};` here over `T t{};`, the latter is even fewer keystrokes.

Answer (score 3):

The class `asio::io_service` derives from noncopyable, which means the copy constructor has been intentionally made inaccessible. This statement won't work for the same reason:

```
boost::asio::io_service io = boost::asio::io_service{};
```

In this instance, the problem is not because of the `auto` keyword, but lack of access to the required constructor. The tutorial code uses the normal constructor, which is public, and so compiles fine.